# how to install software in a new upgrade Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade

I just upgraded my Ubuntu from Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 13.04 but I can't even install any softwares in it. How to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- First enable canonical,multiverse repositories in softwares and updates.
- Update the repositories,

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Then Use software center to install softwares.